getting data with qt c++ qtcpsocket from mission planner
when i want to get data from mission planner with qt c++ , i don't handle with that because of mavlink. i start tcp connection but i don't know what can i do  tcpSocket->write("....here\r\n\r\n");
void MainWindow::on_ardupilot_clicked()
{
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    tcpSocket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1",5760);

    if(tcpSocket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Connected";
        tcpSocket->write("MAV_CMD_NAV_WAYPOINT\r\n\r\n");
        tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);
        tcpSocket->waitForReadyRead(1000); //okumak için bekler
        qDebug() << "reading: " << tcpSocket->bytesAvailable();
        qDebug()<< tcpSocket->readAll();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Not connected!";
    }
}

i tried some commands but it didn't work
MAV_CMD_NAV_WAYPOINT
GET_POSITION 

